# How to unmap mapped drives after exiting a program?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file

I created a batch file to map some drives that a program requires while it is running. But I don't want the drives to be mapped once that program is closed. Is there any way this can be accomplished?

So, user runs batch file, it not only maps drives that the program needs in order to run, but it also starts the executable file of the program itself, but then I want the drives to become unmapped once that program closes. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you run the program with `start /wait`, then you can disconnect the drives after the program terminates.

Comment: Interesting. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am sorry, with this one, I did not even know where to begin. Google searches mostly led me to unrelated results solely about mapping and disconnecting issues. As for using start /wait, that probably doesn't do it when the program itself closes, does it?

Comment: HEY, I think that is it! Start /wait, when I tried it, waits for the program to be closed and it THEN goes to the next command, which I can specify to be unmapping of drives!! Holy sh** thank you AFH!

Comment: If you can please write this as an answer, I can choose it as the answer. Thank you very much.